# How to change v-stepper's step icons size?

Tags: vuetify.js, v-stepper

I am trying to change the [step icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClaaE.png) size (inside a v-stepper).

```
<v-stepper v-model="currentStep">
    <v-stepper-header>
          <v-stepper-item :color="orangeColor" title="Step 1" value="1" id="firstStep"></v-stepper-item>
          <v-divider></v-divider>
          <v-stepper-item :color="orangeColor" title="Step 2" value="2" id="secondStep"></v-stepper-item>
          <v-divider></v-divider>
          <v-stepper-item :color="orangeColor" title="Step 3" value="3" id="thirdStep"></v-stepper-item>
    </v-stepper-header>
</v-stepper>
```

Using Vuetify 3.5.3 version, I didn't find a single method working. I tried to play with the CSS, found multiple methods online, but for older versions of Vuetify.

Does anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`width`, `height` and `font-size` of the `.v-stepper-item__avatar` element seems to affect the icons in question.

For scoped styling use `:deep()` selector:

```css
<style scoped>
  .v-stepper :deep(.v-stepper-item__avatar) {
    width: 40px !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
  }
</style>
```

[demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqtUUtOwzAQvcrgTUBqHNK0C0KoxAlYwK6pKiuZEkv5WM6QAlXvjmOTECqhgsRu/DzvM3rrA2t1FtwrxbsXZDFLCCtVCsJVWgMknS+UsqN9ZE1NQtaoPyELtoRKoYZYGm57l7K192ggCL0ZuGk+TpG3SdlINvTBDoxO2ZDV4OFkw/kKnQNJKtHIW6GHGlMGO0Ndcc6TwO1MlYPJJecM5+cNn/bNPxpGvzAsNP7lxgEaCxlq63nfeusRV+tJ5qSltxKhzRqFzodP6s0R1eUX4PeHbLeiEyT0FRyc217mVMSwuFavcCEr1WgSNd26zwLlc0E//e5MSL+V7xhDqLE6XTj2cW1Ak4wdZyziCx7esH5Y8iXbfADWHtze)